# I want to test my command with codeception

Tags: symfony, testing, syntax, codeception

I want to test my command with codeception but when i run test i get an error

> The syntax of the file, directory, or volume name is incorrect.

This is my code for test

```
public function tryToTest(ApiTester $I)
{
     $I->runShellCommand('talan:create:elastic:index', ['index_name' => 'bddoc', 'attachment' => 'attachment']);
     $I->seeResultCodeIs(0);
}
```

my command work perfectly

```
php bin/console test:create:elastic:index bddoc attachment
```

Comment: Codeception's `runShellCommand` expects you to provide an actual shell command, not a Symfony cli command. You probably need something like this [runSymfonyConsoleCommand](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Symfony#runsymfonyconsolecommand) (requires the Symfony module for Codeception)

Comment: when i use runSymfonyConsoleCommand , I found another error [RuntimeException] Call to undefined method ApiTester::runSymfonyConsoleCommand

Comment: you probably haven't installed the [Symfony module](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Symfony), or something is wrong with the config

Comment: When i use Functional Test I can found this command but i found another error when i run     php vendor/bin/codecept run api functional which is File or path functional not found

Answer (score 1):

I just took a look into the source code of Codeception. You just use the complete string of your command in the first parameter, and the second one is a bool variable, with let the test automatically fail, if the command does not return a `integer == 0`

Here is the documentation: https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Cli

```php
function tryToTest(ApiTester $I)
{
    $I->runShellCommand('php bin/console test:create:elastic:index bddoc attachment');
    $I->seeResultCodeIs(0);
}
```